# What does it mean by "it can be chained multiple times on the same type of object" in the following | ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, semantics

I was reading about how extention methods work in a book named **Altimate ASP.NET Core 3 Web API** recently, then I faced the following section of the book:

> it can be chained multiple times on the same type of object.

The whole section is as following:

> **1.4 Extension methods and CORS Configuration**

> An extension method is inherently a static method. What makes it
> different from other static methods is that it accepts this as the
> first parameter, and this represents the data type of the object which
> will be using that extension method. We’ll see what that means in a
> moment. An extension method must be defined inside a static class.
> This kind of method extends the behavior of a type in .NET. Once we
> define an extension method, **it can be chained multiple times on the
> same type of object**. So, let’s start writing some code to see how it
> all adds up. We are going to create a new folder Extensions in the
> project and create a new class inside that folder named
> ServiceExtensions. The ServiceExtensions class should be static.

As I've just said, my question is about this part: **it can be chained multiple times on the same type of object**.
Would anyone explain that what this sentence refer to or what this sentence ecxactly mean?
In the end, I'm not sure if I'm asking a question in the right place or not! If I have to ask this question in another StackExchange, then please tell me where? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever an extension method returns an instance of the same type, we can use it to chain extension methods. The example below will explain this more clearly.

Let's say we have a class named `Car`:

```
public class Car 
{
    public Car(string brand, string licensePlate, int weight) {
        this.Brand = brand;
        this.LicensePlate = licensePlate;
        this.Weight = weight;
    }

    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

With the following extension methods:

```
public static Car LogBrand(this Car car) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(car.Brand);
    return car;
}

public static Car LogLicensePlate(this Car car) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(car.LicensePlate);
    return car;
}

public static Car LogWeight(this Car car) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(car.Weight.ToString());
    return car;
}
```

Now we can chain the extension methods like this:

```
var myCar = new Car("Volkswagen", "XX-YY-ZZ", 1500);
myCar.LogBrand().LogLicensePlate().LogWeight();
```

The output of this will be:

```
Volkswagen
XX-YY-ZZ
1500
```

Comment: Thanks. Another question, what does it mean by "type of object"? is it referring to "string, int, ...."?

Comment: Yes indeed. In my case the type of object is `Car`. When defining an extension method you have to provide a type, as seen in the example `this Car car`. Please accept the answer if this helped you.